# Compound Machine with Worm and Worm Wheel Drive Velocity Ratio

Tags: gears, mechanisms, mechanical

I'm having trouble understanding the working principle behind solving this worm drive. Here's the question:

A double threaded worm and 40-tooth worm wheel are used to drive a mechanical winch. The efficiency of the machine is 45%. An effort wheel is added to the worm axle, decreasing the efficiency of the compound machine to 36%. Determine the velocity ratio of the added component.

So my first step was to find the efficiency of the added effort wheel since $\eta_{T}=\eta_{1}*\eta_{2}$ so the efficiency of the effort wheel is $\frac{0.36}{0.45}=0.8$. So the velocity ratio of the effort wheel is $VR=\frac{MA}{\eta}$. But we don't know the MA do we? I know the mechanical advantage between the worm and worm wheel is $0.45*20=9$. But I don't know what the mechanical advantage between the effort wheel and worm axle. This was the worked solution:

$$\eta_{Total}=\eta_1*\eta_2$$ $$\eta_2=\frac{0.36}{0.45}=0.8$$ $$VR=\frac{MA}{\eta_2}$$ $$VR=\frac{9}{0.8}$$ $$VR=11.25$$

I can't understand why they have said the MA is 9 here. How do we know that the MA between the effort wheel and worm axle is 9 as well?

Comment: Please don't upload text as images, use MathJax instead: https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/how-can-i-use-mathjax-latex-to-typeset-equations-on-this-site